# After dirty flag check the new tab data is getting loaded in the current tab

Tags: jsf, richfaces

While using JSF richfaces , on change done to a particular tab, dirty flag check is executed in javascript. A confirmation message is displayed while clicking another tab "There are changes made to the current tab, would you navigate to the new tab?". If i click Cancel and remain in the same tab, the new tab data gets loaded in the current screen. Any idea why this behaviour?

Comment: Show the code that you're using.

Comment: <rich:tab name="Person Info" id="tabPersonalInformation" label="PERSON_INFO" onleave='return DirtyFieldHandler.warnUser("#{msgs["common.warn.unsavedTab"]}");'>
  <ui:include...>
   <ui:param name="backingBean" value="#{demograph.personalinfoBean}"/>
 </ui:include>
</rich:tab>

<!-- History -->
<rich:tab name="History" id="history" execute="@this" immediate="true">
 <ui:include src=".....">
  <ui:param name="backingBean" value="#{HistoryTabBean}"/>
 </ui:include>
</rich:tab>

Comment: Edit the question and put the code in there, if you post it like this it's completely unreadable.